# How I can get parts from custom shape

Tags: c#, wpf, shapes

I have a custom shape.

```
public class Procedure : Shape
{
    protected override System.Windows.Media.Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get 
        {
            GeometryGroup gg = new GeometryGroup();
            gg.FillRule = FillRule.Nonzero;
            RectangleGeometry rg = new RectangleGeometry(bound, 10, 10);
            Geometry geometry = label.BuildGeometry(new Point(innerLabelOffsetX, innerLabelOffsetY));

            gg.Children.Add(rg);
            gg.Children.Add(geometry);
            gg.Children.Add(inputPort.Geometry);
            gg.Children.Add(outputPort.Geometry);

            return gg;
        }
    }
}
```

where `bound` is `Rect` and `label` is `FormattedText`. `inputPort` and `outputPort` are my custom shapes.

It looks like this

[image]

I want to get information about clicked part of figure.
How I can do that?

Ex:

1. Click on left circle is message "Input port"
2. Click on right circle is message "Output port"

Comment: are you talking about adding `Context menu Popup`

Comment: @DJKRAZE, what do you mean?

Comment: @DJKRAZE, no, I dont want context menu. I want get information about WHAT you user clicked on composite shape

Comment: then how come you can't create an Event or a Delegate based on which ever MouseButton was Clicked I apologize about the misunderstanding ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform few steps:

0) First, you must define `delegate`, for example in the namespace of your app:

```
public delegate void MouseDownHandler( object sender);
```

1) In your custom shape class you must define event on MouseDownHandler. Like:

```
public event MouseDownHandler MouseDownEvent;
```

2) In the constructor of your custom shape class, you must fill in this string:

```
this.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler(CustomShape_MouseDown);
```

3) After that, define two methods:

```
private void CustomShape_MouseDown(object sender,
 System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
         {
             OnMouseDownHandler(this);
         }

private void OnMouseDownHandler(object sender)
         {
             if (MouseDownEvent != null) { MouseDownEvent(sender); }
         }
```

4) With your custom shape class is over. Now let's write down some code in your UI class:

```
MouseDownHandler _perform_click = new MouseDownHandler(OnCustomShapeMouseDown);

private void OnCustomShapeMouseDown(object sender)
            {
                ...your actions on custom shape click event...like message "Input port" or smth
            }
```

5) And the last step, you must assign the `_perform_click` handler to the handler in a shape class. In the construction method of your UI, for example:

```
_custom_shape.MouseDownEvent += _perform_click;
```

`_custom_shape` is the object of your custom shape class. You can create it in the UI constructor too.

That's it.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I try to perform your instruction and I have an error in last step. In UI class (MainWindow.xaml.cs) I wrote `currentShape.MouseDownEvent += _perform_click;` and I gor an error: **Member 'System.Windows.UIElement.MouseDownEvent' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead**

Comment: Is your currentShape static? This error usually happens because of it. Actually I post you my code that works for me, everything must be ok...

Comment: Well, then try to use you shape class name, not the object instead, or remove static and work with currentShape as I do

Comment: Or the other: try to add static to OnCustomShapeMouseDown.

Comment: it compiled, but doesn't work. I added your code to shape Port. When I clicked on my composite shape I watch in debuger that sender is Procedure. But I want to get Port.

Comment: You click on the Port shape and the sender is Procedure shape? Right? Maybe you subscribed on the _perform_click event of the Port shape Procedure shape instead of Port shape? One more thing: check out that Port shape and Procedure shape are different classes. I mean that if you combine(create) this geometries in one shape class, they will perceived as one solid shape and Click event will be only one for hole this shape.

Comment: Finally you must get component figure, which is combined from 3 objects of classes: Procedure, InputPort, OutputPort, where each class is a shape with her own geometry definition and OnClick event.

Comment: thank you! and the last question: what do you mean "Component figure"? I didn't find it in Google

Comment: I mean your desired shape object, which consist's from three individual parts(shapes) with there own geometries and OnClick events.

Comment: Yeap, but i thought you mean specific wpf class/interface/etc for "Component figure".